# Question about what are included in crash reports

Tags: crash, bug-reporting

If my text editor crashes, it seems to be sure my opened files would be a part of the memory dump. But if my window manager or even the X server crashes, would it be likely including a screenshot of my opened files? Does that file have to be the one on the top to be included?

More seriously, if a keyring manager crashes, would it send my decrypted keys? If no how is this prevented?

Comment: "Send my decrypted keys" ...send where? To whom?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, one can find out easily:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ll /var/crash
total 340
-rw-r----- 1 w3 whoopsie 341500 Aug  4 11:38 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-3.0_libexec_WebKitWebProcess.1003.crash

w3@aardvark:~(0)$ sudo file /var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-3.0_libexec_WebKitWebProcess.1003.crash
/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-3.0_libexec_WebKitWebProcess.1003.crash: ASCII text
```

I have one crash report, and it is `ASCII text`. You can read it (permissions allowing) with any one of the many, many Linux text tools (`more`, `less`, `vi`, `emacs`, `libreoffice`, ...).

It looks like my crash file has the following sections get the size of each section by subtracting the previous line number):

```
w3@aardvark:~(1)$ sudo egrep -n '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+:' /var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-3.0_libexec_WebKitWebProcess.1003.crash
1:ProblemType: Crash
2:Architecture: amd64
3:CurrentDesktop: Unity
4:Date: Thu Aug  4 11:34:52 2016
5:DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
6:ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-3.0/libexec/WebKitWebProcess
7:ExecutableTimestamp: 1458166478
8:ProcCmdline: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-3.0/libexec/WebKitWebProcess 15
9:ProcCwd: /home/w3
10:ProcEnviron:
17:ProcMaps:
5383:ProcStatus:
5425:Signal: 11
5426:Uname: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64
5427:UserGroups: adm cdrom dialout dip libvirtd lp lpadmin mail plugdev root sambashare sudo tty video wireshark
```

I don't see where your user data would go, and upon inspection of my crash file, I don't see any leaking data (beyond what you can glean from the above.

You can inspect your crash files in `/var/crash`.

Comment: How are you expecting to find out whether there is a screenshot or keyring by grepping English words? You can use `apport-unpack` to extract the crash file and the memory dump is in `CoreDump`.

Comment: It might not contain the data in your case, but in all of my crash files there is the line `CoreDump: base64` in the result of `egrep`. And the base64 encoded memory dump follows in the original file.

Comment: That's the memory of the failing process. If it's the X server or Window Manager, all that will be saved is what the X server or Window Manager knows, which doesn't include files opened by sub-sub-sub-processes.